Should I scale my coordinates before least squares?
I assume a linear relationship between a point observed in two coordinate systems:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
l \\ 
y' \\ 
z'  
\end{bmatrix}
=
M_{3x4}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ 
y \\ 
z \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
First row:
$$
l =
\begin{bmatrix}
M_{11} & M_{12} & M_{13} & M_{14} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ 
y \\ 
z \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x & y & z & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
M_{11} \\ 
M_{12} \\ 
M_{13} \\ 
M_{14} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Assume I have n observations of points in both coordinate systems.
Stack n such equations:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 & z_1 & 1 \\
... & ... & ... & ... \\
x_n & y_n & z_n & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
M_{11} \\ 
M_{12} \\ 
M_{13} \\ 
M_{14} 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
l_1 \\ 
... \\ 
l_n 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Likewise:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 & z_1 & 1 \\
... & ... & ... & ... \\
x_n & y_n & z_n & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
M_{21} \\ 
M_{22} \\ 
M_{23} \\ 
M_{24} 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
y'_1 \\ 
... \\ 
y'_n 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 & z_1 & 1 \\
... & ... & ... & ... \\
x_n & y_n & z_n & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
M_{31} \\ 
M_{32} \\ 
M_{33} \\ 
M_{34} 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
z'_1 \\ 
... \\ 
z'_n 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which I can solve by using least squares, thereby finding M.
However the scale of the coordinates are very different:
$$
0 <= l <= 1e4, 0 <= z' <= 50
$$
I am therefore considering scaling my coordinates.
First I could rewrite my first equation:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
l \\ 
y' \\ 
z' \\
1 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
M_{11} & M_{12} & M_{13} & M_{14} \\
M_{21} & M_{22} & M_{23} & M_{24} \\
M_{31} & M_{32} & M_{33} & M_{34} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ 
y \\ 
z \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and introduce:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{l} \\ 
\hat{y'} \\ 
\hat{z'} \\
1  
\end{bmatrix}
=
S_{4x4}
\begin{bmatrix}
l \\ 
y' \\ 
z' \\
1  
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where S is a matrix that scales each coordinate to the range$[-0.5,0.5]$:
$$
S_{4x4}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1/{\Delta l} & 0 & 0 & -\bar{l'}/\Delta l \\ 
0 & 1/{\Delta y'} & 0 & -\bar{y'}/\Delta y' \\ 
0 & 0 & 1/{\Delta z'} & -\bar{z'}/\Delta z'  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\Delta l = max\{l\} - min\{l\}, \bar{l} = 0.5* max\{l\} + 0.5*min\{l\}
$$
thus:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{l} \\ 
\hat{y'} \\ 
\hat{z'} \\
1  
\end{bmatrix}
=
S_{4x4}
\begin{bmatrix}
M_{11} & M_{12} & M_{13} & M_{14} \\
M_{21} & M_{22} & M_{23} & M_{24} \\
M_{31} & M_{32} & M_{33} & M_{34} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ 
y \\ 
z \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Let us introduce:
$$
\hat{M} = SM
$$
and find $\hat{M}$ by least squares and then find M by:
$$
M = S^{-1}\hat{M}
$$
will this approach give me an estimate of M that is more likely than without the scaling?
Should I also scale the $x, y, z$ coordinates? The x coordinate is ca. 20 x larger than the z coordinate.

Not sure about scaling, but I have found it useful when doing any kind of fitting to subtract the mean from the data points and then do the fit. This tends to reduce rounding error considerably.

Metering the velocity of an object in $m/s$ or $Ångström per week$, will that make a differene for the object, the experiment or the experimenter?
